# Django - limit chooses based on the user

Tags: django, python-3.x

I need to limit the staff chooses base on the user who logged in because the staff created from the user my view is `CreateView` and I put the user on all models as `ForignKey` i need help to know how I can limit the choices so you can only see and choose your staff

**forms.py**

```
from unicodedata import name

from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models import Count

from services.models import Service
from staff import views
from staff.models import Staff
from staff.views import staff_view


class AddServiceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    service_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            'class': 'form-control'
        }
    ))

    description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(
        attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
        }
    ))

    price = forms.CharField(widget=forms.NumberInput(
        attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
        }
    ))

    staff = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Staff.objects.all(), empty_label='Choose Staff', widget=forms.Select(
        attrs={
            'class': 'custom-select'
        }
    ))

    class Meta:
        model = Service
        fields = [
            'service_name',
            'description',
            'price',
            'duration',
            'staff',

        ]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from django.views.generic import CreateView, FormView

import staff
from services.forms import AddServiceForm
from services.models import Service
from staff.models import Staff


def service(request):
    services = Service.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    return render(request, 'services.html', {'services': services})


class AddService(CreateView):
    user = User

    model = Service
    form_class = AddServiceForm
    template_name = 'add_service.html'

    def form_valid(self, form, ):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user

        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Please elaborate some more on what is the problem and what you have written to solve it.

Comment: i need to show limited staff that related for the user to choose on of this whene he add service this is the form:

Comment: staff = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Staff.objects.all(), empty_label='Choose Staff', widget=forms.Select(
        attrs={ 'class': 'custom-select'}))

Comment: edit the question above and put it in there instead! It will be easier spotted by someone who knows this field